# Why must $b=0$ for this linear system to have infinitely many solutions for all $a$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

Consider the parameterized linear system of equations represented by the augmented matrix:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & a & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & d-ab-2c & 3-b-2c
\end{array}
\right]
$$
I understand that to have infinitely many solutions, I need fewer rows than there are variables, and no inconsistency.  Therefore I see that $d-ab-2c=0$ and $3-b-2c=0$ are necessary to have infinitely many solutions.

But the question is more specific - it asks to find b,c,d that *for all values of a, there are infinite solutions*.  It's given in the answer that for this to happen, $b=0$ has to be added to the above two conditions.  The explanation I have looks like a tautology "if b is zero, it doesn't matter what a is, for every a we have infinite solutions", and I'd appreciate some insight into why this is so.

Comment: Solutions... to what? Probably you have in mind solving a linear system or matrix equation, but you've omitted important context.  It would help to give a less tautologous explanation if we had some more vocabulary to work with.

Comment: Is the solution for $$[x\quad y\quad z]\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & a & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & d-ab-2c & 3-b-2c
\end{bmatrix}=0$$ the thing you need?

Comment: @Golbez, embarrassingly I don't understand your syntax.  I'm very new to this.  I can say that the above matrix represents the following system: $x + az = 1$, $y + 2z = 2$, and $(d-ab-2c)z = 3-b-2c$.  I can also say in this case, I'm looking to answer the question "What criteria are necessary in order that this system has infinite solutions?"  Does that help you and hardmath to help me?

Comment: Edited original question to clarify that matrix is augmented.  @hardmath, I hope the question is clearer now?

Comment: Yes, this helps a lot.  The idea is clear now that you are solving three linear equations in three unknowns, represented by an augmented matrix.  Are you familiar with *row echelon form* of a matrix and "leading ones" in each row?

Comment: I sure am, and your answer below was great, thanks.  I guess it hadn't been so intuitive that "for a not to matter in this calculation, its coefficient b must be zero", but when you put it like that, it was!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As surmised in the Question, the augmented matrix represents a system with infinitely many solutions if and only if both $d−ab−2c=0$ and $3−b−2c=0$.  If the first of these expressions were nonzero, then the system would have a unique solution, and if it were zero while the second were nonzero, then the system would be inconsistent (have no solution).

So the original linear system can be set aside for now, and focus shifted to when $b,c,d$ would produce infinitely many solutions *for all values of* $a$.  That is, what fixed values of $b,c,d$ would produce:

$$ d−ab−2c=0 \;\text{ and }\; 3−b−2c=0 $$

regardless of what value $a$ is assigned.  Intuitively it is clear that for $a$ not to matter in this calculation, its coefficient $b$ must be zero, but we will show this with a proof.

In particular we must have the above conditions for *both* $a=0$ and $a=1$.  The first requires that we have $d-2c=0$ and $3-b-2c=0$.  The second requires $d-b-2c=0$ and $3-b-2c=0$.  Combining $d-2c=0$ and $d-b-2c=0$ implies $b=0$.

Once we know $b=0$, specific values for $c,d$ also follow.  The Reader should be able to deduce what these specific values are, from the conditions shown above.